# Counting the Number of ways Jobs can be assigned to different Devices

Tags: combinatorics

Please consider the following problem and my solution.
Problem:
There are $20$ identical printing jobs to be sent to $5$ different printers.

(a) One of the printers is much faster than the other four. How many ways are there to distribute the jobs if the
faster printer gets at least $7$ jobs?

(b) One of the printers is almost out of paper. How many ways are there to distribute the jobs so that
the printer that is almost out of paper does not get more than three jobs? (In addition to the fact that the faster one gets at least $7$ jobs)

Answer:

For part (a), we reduce the problem to allocating $13$ jobs to $5$ printers because we must allocate at least $7$ jobs to the
faster printer. Hence the answer is ${13 + 5  - 1}\choose{5-1}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
{{13 + 5  - 1}\choose{5-1}} &=& {{17} \choose {4}} = \frac{17(16)(15)(14)}{4(3)(2)} \\
{{13 + 5  - 1}\choose{5-1}} &=& \frac{17(4)(15)(14)}{3(2)} = 2380 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now for part b. Let $p_3$ be the number we are searching for. Let $p_4$ be the number of ways to send at least $4$ for jobs
to the printer that is low on paper. The way to find $p4$ is to consider the problem of sending $9$ jobs to $5$ printers because
we are sending $7$ jobs to the fast printer and $4$ jobs to the printer low on paper.
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_3 &=& 2380 - p_4 \\
p_4 &=& { {9 + 5 - 1} \choose {5 - 1} } = { {13} \choose {4} } = \frac{ 13(12)(11)(10)  } { 4(3)(2)} \\
p_4 &=& \frac{ 13(3)(11)(10)  } { 3(2) }  = \frac{ 4290 } { 6 } = 715 \\
p_3 &=& 1665
\end{eqnarray*}
The value I got for $p_4$ seems to large to me. I am hoping that somebody can check this for me.
Thanks
Bob

Comment: Your work is correct.